# Create link from value in hidden table

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td style='visibility:collapse'>" . $row['refereeID'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['zone'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['level'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['homephone'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
```

What I am looking to do is to make the lastname a link to a new page based of the refereeID field which will be hidden in the table.  I may not be doing this properly as I suspect that I may not even need to include the 'refereeID' field in the table.

Any advice/help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can just emit a link with that value.  Perhaps something like this:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"somePage.php?refereeID=" . urlencode($row['refereeID']) . "\">" . htmlspecialchars($row['lastname']) . "</a></td>";
```

Since the logic and values are available server-side when the page is being rendered, you don't necessarily need to be concerned with generating the link client-side from values in the table.  You can just explicitly create it inline when rendering the HTML.

If the cell with the ID is no longer needed at that point, go ahead and remove it.

Comment: Thanks @David.  This is what I was thinking based another example that I found.  Would it be advisable to use $refereeID = $GET['refereeID'] at the start of some other page so that I can easily use further details from the db?

Comment: @posselax: Correct, the `somePage.php` referenced in the example link would be able to use the value from `$_GET["refereeID"]` to look up data identified by that ID.  (Remember to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection from that value.)  Also note that I've updated the code in the answer to url-encode and html-encode the output, to avoid problems with unencoded characters and such.

Comment: I'm still very new and learning.  Can you please give me some guidance as to the prepared statement?